# constructor & array in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have my constructor and array built, how do I make it appear in the html file. this is a plus/minus show hide thing.

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>FAQs</title>
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
  </script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="faqs.js"></script>       
</head>

<body>
  <div id="menu">
    <?php
      include "menu.html"
    ?>
  </div>

  <section id="faqs">
    <h1>Phone Book</h1>

    <h2 id="foreign">Import</h2>
    <div>
        <!-- Array for imports goes here-->
    </div>
    <h2 id="muscle">Muscle</h2>
    <div>
        <!-- Array for muscle cars goes here-->     
    </div>
    <h2 id="two">Bikes</h2>
    <div>
        <!-- Array for bikes goes here-->
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the javascript and it does have jQuery in it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // the toggle event method has been removed from jQuery 1.9
    $("#faqs h2").toggle(
        function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("minus");
            $(this).next().show();
        },
        function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("minus");
            $(this).next().hide();
        }

        function contacts(id, type, name, phone) {
            this.id = id;
            this.type = type;
            this.name = name;
            this.phone = phone;
        }

        var auto = new Array();

        auto[0] = new contacts("foreign", "car", "BMW", "867-5309") auto[1] = new contacts("american", "car", "Ford", "224-3425") auto[2] = new contacts("two", "bike", "Harley", "224-9191")

    ); // end toggle

    // here's one way to code this app without the toggle event method
    // but this is by no means the only way

    /*$("#faqs h2").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("minus");
        if ($(this).attr("class") != "minus") {
            $(this).next().hide();
        }
        else {
            $(this).next().show();
        }
    }); // end click*/

}); // end ready
```

the array and/or constructor might be done wrong. so how would i put the array in the html so it would display whats all in the array instead of putting it all in the html file?

Comment: Why are you instantly re-assigning `auto` after you assign it?

Comment: By that, he means that you assign to `auto[0]` twice, then to `auto[1]` and `auto[2]` twice.

Comment: dude, loop through it and print the value in DOM using jquery text()

Comment: ok, i just went ahead and took one of each out

Comment: constructors usually begin with a capital letter by convention, so `function Contacts()`. also you should do `var auto = []`

Comment: It's still far from clear what you want.  First of all is "american" supposed to match "muscle"?  Second, what sort of markup are you looking to get?  Third, why are you mixing together your question about content generation with a seemingly irrelevant section on "toggle"?

Comment: What I am wanting from this is, when every the h2 tag is click, it has a drop down of whatevery the array is. It should be the brand of the car and a  phone number

Answer (score 0):

**[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/txjyt6n2/)** contains one suggestion for adding the content, without worrying about the toggle yet:

```
function Contact(id, type, name, phone) {
    this.id = id;
    this.type = type;
    this.name = name;
    this.phone = phone;
}

var contacts = [
    new Contact("foreign", "car", "BMW", "867-5309"),
    new Contact("foreign", "car", "Mazda", "777-7777"),
    new Contact("muscle", "car", "Ford", "224-3425"),
    new Contact("muscle", "car", "Chevy", "692-2557"),
    new Contact("two", "bike", "Kawasaki", "225-2772"),
    new Contact("two", "bike", "Harley", "224-9191")
]

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.each(contacts, function(index, contact) {
        $("#" + contact.id).append(
            "<div class='contact'>" +
            "<span class='type'>" + contact.type + "</span> " +
            "<span class='name'>" + contact.name + "</span> " +
            "<span class='phone'>" + contact.phone + "</span> " +
            "</div>"
        );
    });
});
```

You would of course have to figure out the markup you really want.

Then adding a toggle on top of it is **[relatively easy](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/zobkekb2/)**:

```
    $("#faqs h2").toggleClass("minus").each(function() {
        $(this).next().hide();
    });

    $("#faqs").on("click", "h2", function(evt) {
        $(this).toggleClass("minus");
        $(this).next().toggle();
    });
```

Note that the constructor function changed to a capitalized form, `Contact`.  But there is probably no reason to actually use a constructor function here.  You're not using the prototype chain; it's not gaining you anything.  This would work just as well:

```
function makeContact(id, type, name, phone) {
    return {
        id: id,
        type: type,
        name: name,
        phone: phone
    };
}

var contacts = [
    makeContact("foreign", "car", "BMW", "867-5309"),
    makeContact("foreign", "car", "Mazda", "777-7777"),
    //...
];
```

Comment: it doesn't do anything. I need to be able to click on the h2 and it drop down a list